# SQL Server Avoid Unique Constraint Violation with Common Table Expression

Tags: sql-server, concurrency

if I have a unique constraint on column department and I don't want SQL to throw a unique constraint violation, instead I would like to NOT update the column if the value already exists on a different row. Is this safe to use (Consistency) if I have two or more users/connections execute the same code at the same time? THANKS!

```
declare @piDepartment varchar(20) = 'test'
declare @piDepartmentSid int = 1105;

WITH CTE
as
(
    select top 1 1 [exists]
    from 
        dbo.tb_Department
    where
        Department = @piDepartment and
        [Department_SID] <> @piDepartmentSid
)
update D set 
    Department = @piDepartment
FROM 
    dbo.tb_Department D
    left join CTE on 1 = CTE.[exists]
where
    D.Department_SID = @piDepartmentSid and
    CTE.[exists] is null;
```

Comment: Can't really understand what you want. Do you want to update the existing row, or create a new one?

Comment: update if @piDepartment does not exist on the table on a different row in order to avoid SQL from throwing a unique constraint violation.

Comment: Why? Is there some benefit not throwing a unique constraint violation? That is kind of why those constraints exist. The checks for them are really fast. And if you are deadset on doing it yourself you can do with an update and include a where exists. And I always find top 1 1 a bit strange to read. I always to stop and look a second time because it is just so obtuse.

Comment: If he did an update with a `where exists()` clause, would that be absolutely concurrency-proof?   I'm thinking he'd need to establish table lock as well with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

A safer way to do this is to keep the unique constraint and use a TRY..CATCH block to avoid raising a constraint violation error when it occurs.